# Yii: Does any way to keep the session unclear after logout

Tags: php, yii

I use the session value to check the current language, but we I logout, all sessions values are cleared and the language changed to default. does any way to keep the session unclear after logout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using session for storing the language is not a good option ( truth is its worst).

**What to use then ?**

You should **either use the cookies** as language is not important or secret data (I think so). Even if the user somehow loses the language he selected, he could select it again and all that will be stored in cookie for as long as you want. To know more about cookies in Yii click [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/152/cookie-management-in-yii/)

**BUT IF**

You for some reason hate cookies(although I will recommend cookies only) then
the second option is **appending the language with the url** in every request like `?lang=en`. This might be a tricky one as you will have to take care of this parameter in every request and url.

Answer (score 1):

How to keep current language after user logs out ?

You can use setComponent() method to set, application components dynamically.
Try by creating a method, say:

```
public function setLanguage(){
 // When User log in  is success, raise a flag, and set in by:
 // Or more specifically, donot copy and paste it, at least give some research and do it something like this.
  Yii::app()->setComponent('language','en');
}
```

And use it, by `Yii::app()->language`;

So, you can here dynamically set and reset your language component.
As [Let me see](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2799319/let-me-see) said, using session for language is not a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work not much sure .
Use `Yii::app()->user->logout(false)`. It will only remove the authentication related information from session and keep the other data there intact.